# HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I keep getting this error trying to run my .NET solution

```
HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation<T>.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, bool doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Prog.SSO.Configuration.InternalTokenHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ApiSetup.cs
+
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler.SendCoreAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync<TResult>(Func<Context, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates<TResult> shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func<DelegateResult<TResult>, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task> onRetryAsync, int permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func<int, DelegateResult<TResult>, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, bool continueOnCapturedContext)
Polly.AsyncPolicy<TResult>.ExecuteAsync(Func<Context, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool continueOnCapturedContext)
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, bool disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass14_0<T, TBody>+<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in RequestBuilderImplementation.cs
Prog.SSO.Quickstart.Account.ExternalController.FindUserFromExternalProvider(AuthenticateResult result) in ExternalController.cs
+
            var userData = await _userDistillery.GetUser(userName);
Prog.SSO.Quickstart.Account.ExternalController.Callback() in ExternalController.cs
+
            var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = await FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I have tried to run the code locally but I do not get any errors and I tried to insure I trust the ssl by running

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

still nothing has worked.

I just pulled this solution down and I noticed one of my sites on my IIS Express (an api) won't load as well and seems to be connected..

Any ideas on what could be causing this or how I could make some progress with this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to recreate the self-signed HTTPS certification for the localhost in IIS of one of my sites running a new framework (.NET 6).

[Here is an article explaining how to do this.](https://improveandrepeat.com/2020/05/recreate-the-self-signed-https-certificate-for-localhost-in-iis-express/)